# Python - Devolver resultados numéricos en forma corta

Tags: python, formato

Quiero hacer un programa en Python que a la hora de mostrar resultados de operaciones numéricas me lo de en forma corta, por ejemplo, que me dé que el resultado es `raíz(10)/5` en lugar de `0.632455532`.
He probado a utilizar el código `Fraction()` con `from fractions import Fraction`, añadiendo `.limit_denominator()` al final del comando pero me devuelve directamente fracciones, no fracciones metiendo raíces y demás.
¿Sabéis si hay alguna manera de que me devuelva los resultados como yo quiero?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Una manera de hacerlo es esta:

```
print ("{0:.3f}".format(5.1234554321))
```

el numero que pongas antes de la letra f es la cantidad de decimales que te imprimirá

este ejemplo imprime la división entre las dos variables y agrega solamente los dos primeros decimales

```
var1 = 10
var2 = 7
resultado = var1 / var2

print ("{0:.2f}".format(resultado))
```